# I can not send using Spread operator array?

Tags: typescript

I have an object "x" which has two properties man, woman and both arrays when I want to use Object.values, I get an Error.I have two questions what type X should have and how to fix the error ... Object.values (x).[code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCKuQbwFDL3gTwC4BnMKUAcwBpd9kBXU8qvbAX2W2wQHsQyyAB7IAvFjp4AtnBBEA2jnr1iAcgKray-E1UNVbeuwC6W-AHdeMuYsnK1Gs9t37D+Ex27YYDEAjDA-MgEyAAUAJRK+FAQYAxQIGEAdCkA8gBGAFYQ-kkAbnAANgwQJKFC4eGePPwkvIUQSYW8lKEEEeFAA)

```
interface DD {
     y:string,
     u:string  
} 

const x = {
    man:[{
        y:'y',
        u:'u'  
    }],
    woman:[{
        y:'y',
        u:'u'  
    }]
}


function y (){
    return  [].concat(...Object.values(x));
}

console.log(y())
```

Comment: `Object.values` is defined for es2017, not sure why the play does not recognize it, it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use an untyped array and concat to it, TypeScript does not allow that because the array item type is incompatible. You can type the empty array, then it will work, e.g.:

```
type Person = { y: string, u: string };
//...
function Y() {
    return ([] as Person[]).concat(...Object.values(x));
}
```

---

If you have `lib` defined in the compiler options you need `"es2017"` or `"es2017.object"` for `Object.values`.

---

If you target a version of JS that supports it, you can also use `Array.prototype.flat` instead (lib: `esnext`):

```
function Y() {
  return Object.values(x).flat();
}
```

Comment: I want to receive Here such result in typescript [JS](https://codesandbox.io/s/m4wm057q59)  ,  [TS Error](https://youtu.be/AxY6jmiqnfQ)